# java script constructor function is not function when called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following function inside  a function constructor :

```
this.show_popup = function(exit_trigger_check)
{    
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: couponspining_ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            action: 'couponspining_event',
            code: 'show_popup',
            wheel_hash: this.wheel_hash,
            preview_key: this.preview_key
        }
    });
    return;
};
```

But when I call in `onClick` event as:

```
<a style="cursor: pointer" onclick="couponspining.show_popup(0);"></a>
```

Its gives in Chrome Console

> couponspining.show_popup is not a function

Comment: Probably `this` is not what you think it is.

Comment: where are you calling the function?

Comment: @AkshayBande see edit

Comment: can you post `couponspining`?

Comment: Have u tried this `<a style="cursor: pointer" onclick="new couponspining().show_popup(0);"></a>`

Comment: try window. show_popup instead of this.

Comment: Have you created couponspining variable? When & Where are you creating it?

Comment: check first are you able to access couponspining there, It must be window context error, when you click or using any timer events then window object goes to root object access that's why you not able to access this function

Comment: @Asutosh Considering `couponspining` is set correctly this should be the right syntax.

Comment: You had better add on Jquery CDN code in your HTML5 code. Try it!
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> Likely it will work. İf it will not have worked, Ask the community again.

Comment: @spc its created as `let couponspining = new couponspining; `

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam did you forget the brackets? it should be `let couponspining = new couponspining();`, plus you should not create a variable with same name as that of constructor function.

Comment: @spc currently its full as: `let couponspining = new couponspining(0);`